# Time durations of the day SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have time durations:

```
11-09-2018 10:00 AM - 11-09-2018 12:00 PM
11-09-2018 4:00 PM  - 11-09-2018 8:00 PM
```

I have a requirement to write a SQL query to derive the other remaining durations for the day 11-09-2018. My query output should be:

```
11-09-2018 12:00 AM - 11-09-2018 9:59 AM
11-09-2018 12:01 PM - 11-09-2018 3:59 PM
11-09-2018 08:01 PM - 11-09-2018 11:59 PM
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a "derive", just a table containing times, which you would join to the date (adding time to date) to get datetimes.

Comment: If you want to improve the question, please provide a) example table and column names (are the durations stored in "from" and "to" columns for example?), and b) any SQL you've been able to come up with.

Comment: Using `[inclusive start, inclusive end]` is usually a bad idea when modelling intervals like this. It's usually better modelled as an *exclusive* end point, so that "11-09-2018 10:00 AM - 11-09-2018 12:00 PM" would be "the times on or after 10am and before 12pm". It then means that the endpoint of each interval is *equal* to the start point of the next interval, which is a) easier to compute and b) doesn't require different computations depending on what the precision of your time data type is (e.g. 9:59am excludes anything that happens *during* that minute before 10am)

Comment: This becomes very tricky if the intervals span more than one day.

Answer (score 0):

please use this for your requirement as general, it is useful when you want to give any date OR datetime as input and want output as given above then you can use following query. Put any date or datetime(timestamp) in place of getdate() and you will get the required output.

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(hh,00,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE())),100) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(mi,59,dateadd(hh,09,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()))),100) +' '+ char(13) + char(10) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(mi,01,dateadd(hh,12,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()))),100) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(mi,59,dateadd(hh,15,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()))),100) +' '+ char(13) + char(10) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(mi,01,dateadd(hh,20,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()))),100) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateadd(mi,59,dateadd(hh,23,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()))),100)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided DDL, I won't write a query, but I will give you an approach you can use.

You need to do some kind of UNION to account for the fact that you may need to create rows both before your first row AND after your last row.

One way you can do it is a "generate a row before each existing row, UNIONed with a last row"

Using a self-join (OUTER) to get a reference to the previous row, SELECT one minute after the previous row's `end time` as the `start time` (COALESCE NULL with '12 AM'), and one minute before the current row's `start time` as the `end time`.  Use a WHERE clause to filter out any row with a `start time` of '12:00 AM'.

This will give you, for each row in your table, the time range before it that you want.

Then you UNION that with a final row, consisting of one minute after the last `end time` as the `start time` and '11:59 PM' as the `end time`.  Use a WHERE clause to filter this row out if the last `end time` is '11:59 PM'.